# Will Java 8 always consume at least 1GB of RAM by default when running inside a container?

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, jvm

We are running a Java application in a Kubernetes cluster. The application itself doesn't have high demand for RAM, but I've noticed that it always consumes 1GB.

```
kubectl top pods
NAME                                                              CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
my-application-c0ffee                                             100m           1127Mi
my-application-c0ffee                                             100m           1109Mi
```

When I checked `jcmd <pid> GC.heap_info` inside the container, I got the following:

```
def new generation   total 89216K, used 12090K [0x00000000bc200000, 0x00000000c22c0000, 0x00000000d2c00000)
  ...
tenured generation   total 197620K, used 151615K [0x00000000d2c00000, 0x00000000decfd000, 0x0000000100000000)
  ...
Metaspace       used 146466K, capacity 152184K, committed 152576K, reserved 1183744K
  class space    used 18171K, capacity 19099K, committed 19200K, reserved 1048576K
```

As I understood, by default Java reserves 1GB of *virtual* memory size for storing Class information (in order to reference it in a compressed manner using 32 bit references this memory block should be reserved beforehand). When running outside of a container that's not a big deal, because this memory is not actually *committed*. It's only an address space that is *reserved*.

But it seems to be completely different situation in case of running inside container, where *reserved* memory becomes *committed*.

Does this mean that Java running in a container will by default consume at least 1GB of RAM?
And is there any other way to deal with that besides explicitly setting `-XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> in case of running inside container, where reserved memory becomes committed

No, reserved memory does not "become committed". The Virtual Size and the Resident Set Size are different metrics, whether in a container or not. What sits in the physical memory is RSS.

`kubectl top` does not show you the RSS, but rather so-called "working set", which does not always match the real memory usage.

> Does this mean that Java running in a container will by default consume at least 1GB of RAM?

No.

> is there any other way to deal with that

It depends on your goals. If you'd like to see the actual container memory statistics, look at `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/.../memory.stats` and `memory.usage_in_bytes`. Or if you use docker, run `docker stats`.

If you'd like to decrease the process' virtual memory instead, turn off `-XX:-UseCompressedClassPointers`.

Comment: I absolutely never understood what to do with that "working set". So your devops see that number, you both look at it... And? Isn't it useless?

Comment: Will this working set memory affect container scheduling (prevent new containers from starting), or can it cause a container to be `OOMKilled`? Should I worry about this 1GB being in the working set?

Comment: @AleksandrErokhin OS will kill a process in a container when cgroup `memory.usage_in_bytes` reaches `memory.limit_in_bytes`. That's the key numbers to care about. Not sure about "working set" (I'm not an expert in k8s), afaik it may affect things like autoscaling.

Comment: @apangin so I've checked the memory statistics and it seems that all the memory shown by top ends up in `rss`. I'd need a deeper look at that I guess.